# How to add search symbol in submit button in HTML file in Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am building a basic app in Rails. I have a page which has a search text field and submit button. The code for it is as follows:

```
    <%= form_tag '#', method: :get, id: 'stock-lookup-form' do %>
    <div class = 'form-group row no-padding text-center col-md-12'>
        <div class = 'col-md-10'>
            <%= text_field :stock, params[:stock], placeholder:'Stock ticker symbol', autofocus: true,
                class: 'form-control search-box input-lg' %>
        </div>
        <div class = 'col-md-2'>
            <%= button_tag(type: :submit, class: 'btn btn-lg btn-success') do %>
                Look up the stock
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I tried doing this in the button_tag:

```
<i class = 'fa fa-search'></i>Look up the stock
```

to get the search symbol in front of the text 'Look up the stock'. But the symbol is not displayed. Any suggestions?

P.S I am working on Rails 5 and have installed bootstrap gem in the application.

Thanks inadvance

Comment: Do you have **font-awesome** installed in the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have font-awesome then you wont be able to get the search icon.
You can add the file directly to your project or can include the CDN to you project like this -

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
```